# Facebook {page_id}/feed api is not returning the comment "from" data in its response

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

Facebook {page_id}/feed api  is not returning the comment data in its response
it only returns the comments for the users that have role on the app

**same for reactions

Im using version 18 of the api, using a page access token on "{page_id}/feed?fields="
im requesting the comments from,name,id,pciture in the fields